# Por qué el evento clic no funciona en js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy aprendiendo NODE con el libro Get Programing with Node js de Johnatan Wexler y en lección 20, se implementa en click event para preguntar al usuario si desea eliminar, el delete funciona pero la ventana de advertencia no aparece.

Este es el código:

```
<a href="<%= `/users/${user._id}/delete?_method=DELETE` %>"
  onclick=" confirm('Are you sure you want to delete
  this record?')">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Cómo puedo hacer que el evento clic funcione?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No funciona porque hay un salto de línea en el texto del confirm.

Solución 1, remover el salto de línea:

```
<a href="<%= `/users/${user._id}/delete?_method=DELETE` %>"
  onclick=" confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Solución 2 usar backtick (`) en lugar de comillas simples:

```
 <a href="<%= `/users/${user._id}/delete?_method=DELETE` %>"
  onclick=" confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete
  this record?`)">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>

<a href="<%= `/users/${user._id}/delete?_method=DELETE` %>" onclick="myFunction()">Delete</a>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```